# IE 11 won't display a website

Tags: windows-7, display, website, internet-explorer-11

I have a 64 bit Windows 7 computer with IE version 11.0.9600.17633.
IE will not display the website http://alistcottagerentals.com, although the site displays perfectly, and quickly in both Chrome and Firefox.

I have disabled all add-ons, cleared the cache, run the website through W3 Validator (no errors), all to no avail.  The site refuses to load and IE ultimately either displays a Time Out error or goes back to the home page.

I've tried to run the site on other computers using IE, but still had no luck getting it to load.

I've even tried changing templates to see if some other code worked and again hit a wall.

Can someone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: I lack the skill set to answer your question, but for an additional data point, my IE 11 behaves in the same manner as your description, while Firefox works the site just fine.

Comment: Microsoft has ended development of IE, so if your site uses newer features that might not have been implemented, perhaps specific support for an HTML5 call, then you'd need to "dumb it down" to work on IE.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, you're right, but as an aside: while Microsoft has ended support, it's still releasing security updates (at least for enterprise licenses). [An August 14th update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4343205) messed up some redirect functionality. (Of course, I don't know if that applies here.)

Answer (score 0):

If it worked earlier this month, and if the original version of the website used a 301 Moved to redirect from the bare domain to `/index.php`, then check if your version of IE11 includes the August 14th 2018 [KB4343205](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4343205):

[image: IE11 About Dialog]

If it does, then it's a known issue with redirects, for which Microsoft has released a fix yesterday, August 31st 2018:

> ## Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer: August 14, 2018
>
> ...
>
> ### Known issues
>
> **Symptom**
>
> In Internet Explorer 11, a blank page may appear for some redirects.
>   Additionally, if you open a site that uses Active Directory Federation
>   Services (AD FS) or Single sign-on (SSO), the site may be
>   unresponsive.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> Refreshing the address bar URL may allow the page to finally load
>   completely.
>
> To resolve this issue, apply update [KB 4459022](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4459022).

Answer (score -2):

According to your description, I try to open this web site, the results show the same as you, and then I used a lot of methods to solve the problem, the result is still unsatisfactory, I think it may be the development of this site technology and IE11 does not match, I suggest you get in touch with the web developer to see if the technology used is incompatible with IE11.

I hope this answer will be helpful to you.